# Android - ViewSwitcher is not switching views

Tags: android, viewswitcher

It should be easy, right? So - here's how I have `ViewSwitcher` defined in XML (Id's and layouts omitted for brevity)

```
<ViewSwitcher android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" >       
    <!-- First view, comes up OK --> 
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header1">
        <!-- some more controls: Progress bar, test view and the button -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- second view. changing to the actual (not include) layout has no effect -->
    <include android:id="@+id/header2" />
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Then somewhere in my Java code I have this code

```
ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.profileSwitcher);
// more code that basically executes background search
// when call comes back - switch
switcher.bringToFront(); // does nothing
// switcher.bringChildToFront(findViewById(R.id.header2)); // no effect ether
```

It's just not switching. I develop for API v. 3 (1.5+) and to my surprise there are very few references to ViewSwitcher. I'm I missing something obvious here?

P.S. I just found out by brute force that this works:

```
switcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

Still - why no luck with `bringToFront()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`bringToFront()` actually has nothing to do with `ViewSwitcher`, the method is inherited from View class and stands for z-order manipulation of current view: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()

You have to use `showNext()` and `showPrevious()` methods inherited from `ViewAnimator`.

Comment: Right, good point. I guess I just went with my intuition which is not very safe

Answer (score 22):

In `ViewSwitcher` to navigate between views you can use the methods `showPrevious()` and `showNext()`

Or use also can go to specific view by `setDisplayedChild(int index)` method where index can be either `0` or `1`